# pageblock header show before click search button

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, header-bar

I have a visualforce page with a search button, and when clicked shows a candidate name in a page block table.

My problem is that before I click the search button, the pageblock table header is displayed without information.

This is my code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Candidate__c" showheader="false"
        extensions="cansearchcontroller">  
    <apex:form>  
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" label="Input" />   
        <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}"
                rerender="Appear"/>  
        <apex:commandButton value="Clear records" action="{!search}"  />  
        <apex:messages /> 
        <apex:outputPanel id="Appear">
            <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" >
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!can}" var="a">  
                    <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>    
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!app}" var="b">  
                    <apex:column value="{!b.Status__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!b.Job__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>   
            </apex:pageBlock> 
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>     
</apex:page>
```

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying that you don't want the table headers to appear before the search is done then you can add `rendered` to each table so that the table only appears when there are rows:

```
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!can}" var="a" rendered="{! can.size > 0}">  
                <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>    
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!app}" var="b" rendered="{! app.size > 0}">  
                <apex:column value="{!b.Status__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!b.Job__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

But make sure that the `can` and `app` lists are initialised to empty lists and not null in your controller.

Comment: Yes, give me this error
The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'
How can I change my controller?

Comment: Include `can = new List<Candidate__c>()` in your constructor and the equivalent for `app`.